# Why does libvirt require root privileges by default?

Tags: permissions, kvm, non-root-user, libvirt

I have tried accessing libvirt (with virt-manager, or with virsh), and there are often issues with permissions.  I found out from [this blog post](https://major.io/2015/04/11/run-virsh-and-access-libvirt-as-a-regular-user/) that it is possible to add a Polkit rule to allow a regular user to access the libvirt daemon.

So I was wondering, is there a good reason why libvirt defaults to requiring root privileges?  I don't know how polkit works, so perhaps this is less secure than it seems, or maybe there is some other drawback to doing things this way.

Answer (score 2):

Access to the system libvirtd is most likely root-equivalent in your default configuration.  libvirt does not require root access by default though, if you use qemu:///session.

E.g. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1284447

https://web.archive.org/web/20150905195134/https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/45805/how-to-use-virt-manager-as-a-non-root-user/